# ReactJS bootstrap button as a link (new tab)

Tags: reactjs, href, react-bootstrap, react-button

I investigated a lot of topics about using button as a link but didn't found a solution for me - I need to open a certain page in a new tab using React bootstrap button.

```
<Button onClick={() => onClickOpenVacancy(id)}>
```

[React bootstrap offers a prop](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/) 'href' but no info how to open in new tab. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `href` and `target` together:

```
<Button href="URL" target="_blank" onClick={() => onClickOpenVacancy(id)}>
```

It looks like they just leave [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#target) with type `any` without further documentation. It just works the same way as the attribute that exists on the usual `<a>` tag does.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the button inside the anchor tag

```
 <a href='https://example.com/' target="_blank">
        <button className="test" onClick={() => onClickOpenVacancy(id)}>
            Click Here
        </button>
 </a>
```

or

```
   <button className="test" 
       onClick="window.location.href = 'https://example.com" target="_blank">
        Click Here
    </button>
```

or..not really needed for you still a way would be

```
<form action="https://example.com/" target="_blank">
        <button className="test" type="submit" onClick={}> // onClick not needed
            Click Here
        </button>
    </form>
```

If `onClickOpenVacancy` was meant to do the redirection, then you don't need onClick function. the href and target are enough.

Comment: In my case correct code is
```<Button target="_blank" href={onClickOpenVacancy(id)}>```
Of course function is no needed here. onClickOpenVacancy just returns me URL string

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the complete URL in this code snippet and it should work

```
<Button onClick={() => window.open(URL, '_blank')}>ID</Button>
```

It's nothing specific to library like bootstrap, etc